# More questions with some jQuery codes

Tags: jquery, ajax

I've made a form that sends data via Ajax, but when it is supposed to delete all values from the form, (**form.trigger('reset');**) it doesn't do that, either it stays with the text i entered.

Can You help me with the removal?

```
$(document).ready(function() {
  var form = $('#form'); // contact form
  var submit = $('#submit');  // submit button
  var alert = $('.alert'); // alert div for show alert message

  // form submit event
  form.on('submit', function(e) {
    e.preventDefault(); // prevent default form submit

    $.ajax({
      url: 'query.php?action=chat', // form action url
      type: 'POST', // form submit method get/post
      dataType: 'html', // request type html/json/xml
      data: form.serialize(), // serialize form data 
      beforeSend: function() {
        alert.fadeOut();
        submit.html('Sending....'); // change submit button text
      },
      success: function(data) {
        alert.html(data).fadeIn(); // fade in response data
        form.trigger('reset'); // reset form
        submit.html('Send Email'); // reset submit button text
      },
      error: function(e) {
        console.log(e)
      }
    });
  });
});
```

Comment: Please edit the title to something more descriptive.

Answer (score 2):

`$('#form')[0].reset();` should clear form as well .

Comment: `reset` is a method on the native DOM `form` element, so it should be `$('#form')[0].reset();`

Comment: when i submit it the content stays there, can you give me the code in order to do that, ( delete the form content )

Comment: In your question you asked to remove values from form inputs . Not sure what "delete the form content" means . do you want to remove entire form html from page ?